# Allocating sequential memory addresses for array in structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, struct, malloc

I would like to know how to allocate sequential memory for an array of structures inside of another structure. Say I have struct1 which has an array of struct2, I would like to have it all in one sequential block of memory.

I could use malloc to allocate the block, but how would I assign the array's memory?

```
struct1 *set = malloc(sizeof(struct1) + sizeof(struct2)*number_of_structs);
set->arr = (struct2*)set + sizeof(struct); //This is probably wrong
set->arr[0].data = 1;
set->arr[1].data = 2; 
...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *flexible array member* :

```
#define NUM_ELEM  42

struct a {
   /* whatever */    
};

struct b {
    int c;
    struct a d[];  // flexible array member
};

struct b *x = malloc(sizeof *x + NUM_ELEM * sizeof x->d[0]);
```

Comment: Actually, what if I couldn't use flexible arrays? Is there any other way?

Comment: If your compiler does not support c99, you can use the old method called the *struct hack*: just use `struct a d[1];` instead of `struct a d[];` in `struct b` declaration and allocate for one element less: `malloc(sizeof *x + (NUM_ELEM - 1) * sizeof x->d[0])`

Answer (score 2):

This way is used in some Windows API, it may look like this:

```
struct struct1
{
     // some members ...

     struct struct2 arr[1];
}

struct1 *set = malloc(sizeof(struct1) + sizeof(struct2) * (number_of_structs-1));
```

set->arr points to array of `number_of_structs` members. struct1 always contains at least one struct2 inside + other struct2 members in contiguous memory block.